# How to parse this JSON with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'am struggling with a problem to parse a JSON with GSON which contains lists as values. This should be pretty simple, but I can't figure out how to solve it. The JSON is:

```
{
  "key1": [
    "foo1",
    "foo2",
    "foo3"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "foo4",
    "foo5",
    "foo6"
  ],
  "key3": [
    "foo7",
    "foo8",
    "foo9"
   ]
}
```

I think the best way is to put it into a `Map<String, List<String>>`, but I can't create a `Type` for it. Like:

```
Type jsonArrayType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
// Doesn't work, causes exception: "com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.List"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get a `java.lang.reflect.Type` from the `getType()` method. Use that to parse your json. Here is a small working example (Java 7)

```
String json = "{\"key1\": [\"foo1\",\"foo2\",\"foo3\"],\"key2\": [\"foo4\",\"foo5\",\"foo6\"],\"key3\": [\"foo7\",\"foo8\",\"foo9\"]}";
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, List<String>> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
System.out.println(map);
```

This snippet prints the below value

> {key1=[foo1, foo2, foo3], key2=[foo4, foo5, foo6], key3=[foo7, foo8, foo9]}

Comment: I shouldn't be awake till 7am.. I had some errors in my code which caused the mentioned exception. Also I had to parse my JSON string to a JsonElement first. But you're right. Your code is working and it showed me where I was wrong. Thank you very much :-)